# Custom image data augmentation causes memory leak in TensorFlow2.0

Tags: python, memory-leaks, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, data-augmentation

I am working on Region Proposal Network for object detection. If I want to augment my data I need to augment both images and corresponding bounding boxes (e.g. scale, rotate, ...) + I have also image mask as an input, which I need to augment too. So I made custom function(s) for data augmentation.

The pipeline is as follows:

1. I create `tf.data.Dataset` from python generator, which contains loaded image, label (bounding boxes coordinates) and mask:

```
    tf_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: data_generator(img_paths, annotations),
                                                output_shapes={'images': tf.TensorShape([None, None, 3]),
                                                               'labels': tf.TensorShape([None, 4]),
                                                               'masks': tf.TensorShape([None, None, 1])},
                                                output_types={'images': tf.float32,
                                                              'labels': tf.int32,
                                                              'masks': tf.uint8})

    if use_augument:
        tf_dataset = augment_dataset(tf_dataset)
```

code continues with some additional expansion but this part is important because when I add augmentations it starts to cause memory leak.

2. Function `augment_dataset(tf_dataset)` calls dataset augmentations. Everything works fine except one augmentation (all augmentations are made as this one but only this one causes really high memory leak (RAM usage)):

```
    dataset = dataset.map(
        lambda x: tf.cond(
            tf.keras.backend.random_uniform([], 0, 1) > 0.0,
            lambda: aug.shrink(
                x,
                vertical=tf.keras.backend.random_uniform([], 0.8, 2),
                horizontal=tf.keras.backend.random_uniform([], 0.8, 2)
            ),
            lambda: x
        ), num_parallel_calls=8
    )
```

3. Function `aug.shrink(tensor: tf.Tensor, vertical: float = 1, horizontal: float = 1)` resizes image, label and mask based on `vertical` and `horizontal` ratio.
   My network accepts dynamic size of image (reason to use `tf.shape`) and label (bounding box) is in format `(xcenter, ycenter, width, height)`:

```
def shrink(tensor: tf.Tensor, vertical: float = 1, horizontal: float = 1):
    image = tensor['images']
    label = tensor['labels']
    mask = tensor['masks']

    height = tf.cast(tf.shape(image)[0], tf.float32) / vertical
    width = tf.cast(tf.shape(image)[1], tf.float32) / horizontal

    height = tf.cast(height, tf.int32)
    width = tf.cast(width, tf.int32)

    # resize image
    resize_image = tf.image.resize(image, (height, width))
    resize_mask = tf.image.resize(mask, (height, width))
    resize_mask = tf.cast(resize_mask, tf.uint8)

    div_tensor = [horizontal, vertical, horizontal, vertical]
    new_label = tf.math.divide(tf.cast(label, tf.float32), div_tensor)
    new_label = tf.cast(new_label, tf.int32)

    return {'images' : resize_image, 'labels' : new_label,'masks' : resize_mask}
```

I have also tried a version with `tf.py_function`, where I used combination of OpenCV and numpy for resizing but it did not work. Does anyone encountered such a problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you found the issue ?

Comment: Hello Ludo. No, I did not but I have made a small workaround and implemented all augmentations outside `tf.data.Dataset` (in this case in `data_generator` function).